# How to sort a numpy array based on the both arrays and also conditions

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, conditional-statements

I have a numpy array with three columns and hundres of rows. I want to sort it based on two columns and in cases also regard the third column in my sorting. This is my input (they are `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates):

```
my_point=np.array([[1., 2., 90.9],
                   [1., 0., 100.1],
                   [1.8, 0., 2.8],
                   [1.8, 2., 3.1],
                   [1.8, 1., 2.7],
                   [3., 0., 3.],
                   [3., 2., 2.9],
                   [2., 1., 100.],
                   [2., 0., 100.]])
```

Firstly, I want to sort it based on the first (`x`) and second column (`y`) and secondly modify this sort based on the third column (`z`). The key issue is that I must sort my data based on `x` and `y` and cannot change it to `x` and `z` or `y` and `z`, because then it changes the order of all the points. This is my sorting code:

```
result_array=my_point[np.lexsort((my_point[:,1],my_point[:,0]))]
```

It gives me:

```
array([[1., 0., 100.1],
       [1., 2., 90.9],
       [1.8, 0., 2.8],
       [1.8, 1., 2.7],
       [1.8, 2., 3.1],
       [2., 0., 100.],
       [2., 1., 100.],
       [3., 0., 3. ],
       [3., 2., 2.9]])
```

It is correct but I want to modify my sort based on the third column. I want to consider the values of this column, when it is highly different from the adjacent rows. As `result_array` shows, third column of its second, third and fourth rows (`[1.8, 0., 2.8]`, `[1.8, 1., 2.7]` and `[1.8, 2., 3.1]`) have very low values compared to the next two rows. The `x` value of these rows is just a little bit higher than next ones and in such cases I want to neglect it and give priority to `z` values:

```
array([[1., 0., 100.1],
       [1., 2., 90.9],
       [2., 0., 100.],
       [2., 1., 100.],
       [1.8, 0., 2.8],
       [1.8, 1., 2.7],
       [1.8, 2., 3.1],
       [3., 0., 3. ],
       [3., 2., 2.9]])
```

For more clarity, I have uploaded a fig showing my desired order of points in 3d space. I think It can be done maybe through defining a function for sorting but I have no idea on how to do it.
In advance, I do appreciate any help.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a sort function like

```py
sortfunc = my_point[:, 0] * 100 + my_point[:, 1] * 10 - my_point[:, 2]

idx = np.argsort(sortfunc)
my_point[idx]
# array([[  1. ,   0. , 100.1],
#        [  1. ,   2. ,  90.9],
#        [  2. ,   0. , 100. ],
#        [  2. ,   1. , 100. ],
#        [  1.8,   0. ,   2.8],
#        [  1.8,   1. ,   2.7],
#        [  1.8,   2. ,   3.1],
#        [  3. ,   0. ,   3. ],
#        [  3. ,   2. ,   2.9]])
```

Of course the coefficients `100`, `10`, and `-1` are then a matter of tuning.

Comment: Dear @Nils Werner, Sorry for my late feed back. Since yesterday I was working with my data. Your method as completely fine but with the new data, I have a big problem and cannot tune the coeficients at all. Do you know any other way to do it.

Comment: No, but I suggest you just open another question with the new data and problems.

Comment: Dear @Nils Werner, Thanks for your help. I do appreciate it.